# WiFi error wpa_supplicant

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I have a problem with the `wpa_supplicant` program.

My problem is about the use of `wpa_cli` which needs `wpa_supplicant`. Error when I'm executing `sudo wpa_cli`:

```
Could not connect to wpa_supplicant
```

The manual start of `wpa_supplicant` gives me some errors:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=0   ### NEW!!!
```

Config **dhcp**

```
## /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
   range 192.168.2.2 192.168.2.9;
   option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
   option domain-name "home";
   option routers 192.168.2.1;
}
```

Config **wpa_supplicant**

```
## /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
# network={
#   ssid="__SSID__"
#   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
#   psk="__PASS__"
#   id_str="home"
# }
```

Config **hostapd**

```
## /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
interface=wlan0
driver=rtl871xdrv
ieee80211n=1
ssid=__SSID__
hw_mode=g
channel=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=__PASS__
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

# EDIT
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
```

Results of `ifconfig` / `iwconfig`

```
wlan0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:4a:00:17:40:fd
          inet adr:192.168.2.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"__SSID__"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Master  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: C0:4A:00:17:40:FD
          Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

How can I start `wpa_supplicant` without errors and have `wpa_cli` connect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, the written errors didn't affect the system.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like (only wlan part) :

```
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    pre-up wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
```

With this config, I can use the `sudo wpa_cli` command without error !

Thanks to **peterph** anyway :) !

Comment: I was looking for this for hours. The last line fixed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The errors `wpa_supplicant` produces are not *necessarily* related to your `wpa_cli` connection problem. The trouble here is that `wpa_cli` is unable to establish connection with `wpa_supplicant` - unable to open the control socket. This can have several causes:

1. user running `wpa_cli` is unable to access the socket given e.g. in `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

   ```
   ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
   ```

   You need to check that files in that directory are accessible to the user under which `wpa_cli` runs. That means not just the sockets being `rw` - all above directories have to be at least `x`, the last one probably also `r` so that `wpa_clie` can list all available sockets.
2. Unlike `wpa_supplicant`, `wpa_cli` is not DBus capable. Make sure `wpa_supplicant` is not listening via DBus only. Judging by your configuration files this is *probably not* your case.
3. `wpa_supplicant` not running (as per comments below). This would indicate, that there indeed might be a connection between the error messages emitted by `wpa_supplicant` and not being able to connect to it. To make sure run it in verbose mode (`-d` or even `-dd`) **and not daemonizing** (which is the default - just make sure you are not using the `-B` option). You can also watch out for the control socket, e.g.:

   ```
   watch -n 0.1 "ls -al /var/run/wpa_supplicant"
   ```

   Remember that most of these commands need to be run with root privileges, so for debugging it might be easier to just `su - root` permanently rather than prefixing each command with `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About your first point, I have to tell you that the file `/var/run/wpa_supplicant` does not exist.. Do you think this is the problem ?

Comment: It is created by `wpa_supplicant` when needed. If it doesn't exist **while** it is running, then option 2 suddenly becomes more likely. :)

Comment: Okay, but I don't really know how to apply your option 2.. You're sepaking about a "main application", but I'm just using the commands I spoke about `wpa_cli` and `wpa_supplicant`, and I don't know how to avoid dbus only.. I had to tell you that `rfkill list` is giving me errors too (if it's related) "Can't open RFKILL device: No such file or directory".. I'm really lost

Comment: main applicatin = `wpa_supplicant` - I've fixed it, it was a bit misleading indeed. Socket: check `lsof | grep wpa_supplicant` (when you have it running) - it should show you the open socket. As for `rfkill` - is `/dev/rfkill` accessible for the user running `rfkill`?

Comment: I tried the `lsof | grep wpa_supplicant` command, but it doesn't return a result. Btw, I think my problem is that `wpa_supplicant` is not starting.. I tried a `ps -e | grep wpa` and it's empty too. About `rfkill`, `/dev/rfkill` doesn't exist for me..

Comment: missing `/dev/rfkill` could explain *"Cannot open RFKILL control device"*, let me update my answer...

Comment: I tried with the -d option and I can see some errors. Full log [here](http://pastebin.com/qCwraw5r). I have to tell you again, what I want with my WiFi install is just the hotspot mode (if it can helps ; I don't care about internet access over WiFi).. I also edited my post to add a new info in the result of `wpa_supplicant` : `wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=0`. That can maybe help to locate the problem..

Comment: "sudo wpa_cli" solved the "problem" in m case.

Comment: To make the rfkill work, the kernel should have been compiled with CONFIG_RFKILL=y (If you use buildroot, set this in the config file in the boards directory) and you should have compiled the userspace package called rfkill. (If you use buildroot, set this in your defconfig: BR2_PACKAGE_RFKILL=y). If your have purchased the platform with preloaded kernel/rootfs, then you might not have access to the toolchain, but if you do, please recompile the kernel image and the rootfs